# How to deserialize a non-standard size field?

Tags: serialization, go, binary, bit-fields

I have to deserialize some binary messages coming from another application. I would love to use [restruct.io](http://restruct.io) but some fields in the message structure use a "non-standard" number of bits ( 5 bits, 3 bits, ... 10 bits ... ).

Is there any way to handle this type of structs? I have been searching for some time without any success so any help will be very welcomed.

thanks in advance

I wil try to give an example to clarify my question. Given the code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"

    restruct "gopkg.in/restruct.v1"
)

type MessageType uint8

const (
    MessageTypeOne MessageType = iota + 1
    MessageTypeTwo
    MessageTypeThree
)

// Message is the data to deserialize from the binary stream
type Message struct {
    Length     uint32      `struct:"uint32"` // message size in bytes (including length)
    Type       MessageType `struct:"uint8"`
    Version    uint8       `struct:"uint8:4"` // Just need 4 bits
    Subversion uint8       `struct:"uint8:2"` // just need 2 bits
    Optional   uint8       `struct:"uint8:1"` // just one bit --> '1' means next field is NOT present
    NodeName   string      ``
    ANumber    uint16      `struct:"uint16:10"` // just need 10 bits
}

// (length(4)+type(1)+(version(4bits)+Subversion(2bits)+Optional(1bit))) = 6 bytes
// need 32bit alignment
func main() {
    var inStream = []byte{0x08, // just 8 bytes needed
        0x01,       // messge type = MessageTypeOne
        0x4a,       // Version=0100 Subversion=10 Optional=1 ANumber = 0 (MSB bit)
        0x00, 0x60, // ANumber(000 0000 011) Padding = 0 0000 for 32 bits alignment
    }
    var msg Message

    err := restruct.Unpack(inStream, binary.BigEndian, &msg)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(msg)
    // Expected:
    // msg.Length = 8
    // msg.Type = 1
    // msg.Version = 4
    // msg.Subversion = 2
    // msg.Optional = 1
    // msg.NodeName = ""
    // msg.ANumber = 3
}
```

I will receive inStream from a TCP connection and will want to deserialize the binary data and get a Message struct with the expected values ...

Hope this will clarify my question.

Thanks again ;)

Comment: Of course there's some way to handle it, but we need to know what the format is if you want assistance. Please provide an example of what you're tying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been working on some patch for restruct.io to be able to work with bitfields .... Still not fully tested but seems to work ...

Will try to send a pull request once tested ...

```
func (e *encoder) writeBits(f field, inBuf []byte) {

    var inputLength uint8 = uint8(len(inBuf))

    if f.BitSize == 0 {
        // Having problems with complex64 type ... so we asume we want to read all
        //f.BitSize = uint8(f.Type.Bits())
        f.BitSize = 8 * inputLength
    }

    // destPos: Destination position ( in the result ) of the first bit in the first byte
    var destPos uint8 = 8 - e.bitCounter

    // originPos: Original position of the first bit in the first byte
    var originPos uint8 = f.BitSize % 8
    if originPos == 0 {
        originPos = 8
    }

    // numBytes: number of complete bytes to hold the result
    var numBytes uint8 = f.BitSize / 8

    // numBits: number of remaining bits in the first non-complete byte of the result
    var numBits uint8 = f.BitSize % 8

    // number of positions we have to shift the bytes to get the result
    var shift uint8
    if originPos > destPos {
        shift = originPos - destPos
    } else {
        shift = destPos - originPos
    }
    shift = shift % 8

    var inputInitialIdx uint8 = inputLength - numBytes
    if numBits > 0 {
        inputInitialIdx = inputInitialIdx - 1
    }

    if originPos < destPos {
        // shift left
        carry := func(idx uint8) uint8 {
            if (idx + 1) < inputLength {
                return (inBuf[idx+1] >> (8 - shift))
            }
            return 0x00

        }
        mask := func(idx uint8) uint8 {
            if idx == 0 {
                return (0x01 << destPos) - 1
            }
            return 0xFF
        }
        var idx uint8 = 0
        for inIdx := inputInitialIdx; inIdx < inputLength; inIdx++ {
            e.buf[idx] |= ((inBuf[inIdx] << shift) | carry(inIdx)) & mask(idx)
            idx++
        }

    } else {
        // originPos >= destPos => shift right
        var idx uint8 = 0
        // carry : is a little bit tricky in this case because of the first case
        // when idx == 0 and there is no carry at all
        carry := func(idx uint8) uint8 {
            if idx == 0 {
                return 0x00
            }
            return (inBuf[idx-1] << (8 - shift))
        }
        mask := func(idx uint8) uint8 {
            if idx == 0 {
                return (0x01 << destPos) - 1
            }
            return 0xFF
        }
        inIdx := inputInitialIdx
        for ; inIdx < inputLength; inIdx++ {
            //note: Should the mask be done BEFORE the OR with carry?
            e.buf[idx] |= ((inBuf[inIdx] >> shift) | carry(inIdx)) & mask(idx)

            idx++
        }
        if ((e.bitCounter + f.BitSize) % 8) > 0 {
            e.buf[idx] |= carry(inIdx)
        }
    }

    //now we should update buffer and bitCounter
    e.bitCounter = (e.bitCounter + f.BitSize) % 8

    // move the head to the next non-complete byte used
    headerUpdate := func() uint8 {
        if (e.bitCounter == 0) && ((f.BitSize % 8) != 0) {
            return (numBytes + 1)
        }
        return numBytes
    }

    e.buf = e.buf[headerUpdate():]

    return
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While there's probably no generic package to implement this custom struct packing, you can easily create your own method extracting just the bits required for each field.

```
func (m *Message) UnmarshalBinary(data []byte) error {
    m.Length = binary.BigEndian.Uint32(data[:4])

    if int(m.Length) > len(data) {
        return fmt.Errorf("not enough bytes")
    }

    m.Type = MessageType(data[4])

    m.Version = data[5] >> 4
    m.Subversion = data[5] >> 2 & 0x03
    m.Optional = data[5] >> 1 & 0x01

    // move the index for ANumber back if there's an optional string
    idx := 6
    if m.Optional == 0 {
        // remove the last two bytes for ANumber
        end := int(m.Length) - 2
        m.NodeName = string(data[6:end])
        idx = end
    }

    m.ANumber = uint16(data[idx]&0xc0)<<2 | uint16(data[idx]&0x3f<<2|data[idx+1]>>6)
    return nil
```

}

You can of course add more bound checks to return errors rather than letting this panic when indexing out of bounds.

I modified your `inStream` slice slightly to match your definition, and you can see the example output here: https://play.golang.org/p/FoNoazluOF

Comment: Thanks for your answer ... good code it set my path to the way I am doing it right now.